# Change key value by the given time in PHP

Tags: php

I have 4 keys and I want to change the key value after 6 hours.

That means after every 6 hours function will get the next key from array or some .txt file and assign it to the script.

Right now I am using random function for that but I want to use the time interval function

```
$random = array('key1','key2','key3','key4');
$key = $random[array_rand($random, 1)];
```

Comment: and how the script run after every 6 hour?? Do you call it using ajax or want to know about **cron**???

Comment: I can run cronjob, but is there a way to change key value without using cronjob or ajax?

Comment: yes, you can manually do it using server time and global variable, also need database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$h = (int)date('H');
$keys = array('key1','key2','key3','key4');
$key = $keys[floor($h / 6)];
```

Comment: with your suggestion its still using random function, but I want to use the next key after every 6 hours, not randomly

Comment: No, this is not random. It will change every 6 hours. I just left name you had :)

Comment: Ok, I changed name of array to not confuse you :)

Comment: ok with your new suggestion the key will change after every 6 hours? like it will change to next key? and after the 4th key it will start from the key1 right?

Comment: No, it will change every 6 hours not every 1 hour. You have 4 keys each for every 6 hours

Comment: yes i forgot to mention 6, so what happen when the 4th key time will finish, should it return to key1?

Comment: You will have periods: 0-5, 6-11,12-17, 18-23. And yes, when another day will start you will back to key1 and so on

Comment: You can easily test it by changing manually value of `$h`, eg `$h=23;` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$keysFromFile = array('key1','key2','key3','key4');

$h = (int)date('H');


if($h <= 5)
    $key = $keysFromFile[0];
elseif($h >= 6 && $h <= 11)
    $key = $keysFromFile[1];
elseif($h >= 12 && $h <= 17)
    $key = $keysFromFile[2];
else //$h >= 18 && $h <= 23
    $key = $keysFromFile[3];


echo $key;
```

Comment: Yours IF are redundant. It all can be done by one simple line `$key = $keysFromFile[floor($h / 6)];` as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I've added this variant to show all conditions of this problem :) +1 for your answer!

Comment: Yes, in yours code we can see all periods which will have :)